# How to match patterns "begins with A or ends with B" with Python regular expression?

Tags: python, regex

```
r'(^|^A)(\S+)(B$|$)'
```

results to matches everything, which actually equals to ^\S$.

How to write one matches "begins with A or ends with B, may both but not neither?"

PS: I also need refer to group (\S+) in the substring module.

Example:

Match `Aanything`, `anythingB`, and refer `anything` group in the replace.

Comment: ASDF -> SDF, SDFB -> SDF, but ASDFB -> SDFB or SDF?

Comment: So it's a Python regex. Please tag the language you're using as different languages implement different regex flavors, and regexes provided in other languages may not be compatible with Python's regex engine.

Comment: thanks, problem solved. this is my first time posting in stackoverflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Problem solved.**

I use this regex in python, I found this in the Python manual:

> `(?(id/name)yes-pattern|no-pattern)`
>   Will try to match with yes-pattern if
>   the group with given id or name
>   exists, and with no-pattern if it
>   doesn’t. no-pattern is optional and
>   can be omitted. For example,
>   (<)?(\w+@\w+(?:.\w+)+)(?(1)>) is a
>   poor email matching pattern, which
>   will match with '' as
>   well as 'user@host.com', but not with
>   '
>
> New in version 2.4.

**So my final answer is:**

```
r'(?P<prefix>A)?(?P<key>\S+)(?(prefix)|B)'
```

Commands:

```
>>>re.sub(r'(?P<prefix>A)?(?P<key>\S+)(?(prefix)|B)','\g<key>',"Aanything")
```

'anything'

```
>>>re.sub(r'(?P<prefix>A)?(?P<key>\S+)(?(prefix)|B)','\g<key>',"anythingB")
```

'anything'

While `AanythingB` give me `anythingB` back, but I don't care anyway.

```
>>>re.sub(r'(?P<prefix>A)?(?P<key>\S+)(?(prefix)|B)','\g<key>',"AanythingB")
```

'anythingB'

Comment: wouldn't be `if re.match(r'^A\S+$', s): s = s[1:]`; `if re.match(r'^\S+B$', s): s = s[:-1]` much simpler?

Comment: your final answer has unbalanced parenthesis :)

Comment: Shouldn't the condition be on `A`?  Oh, it is on the samples, but not in the "final answer"...

Comment: A more complete regex would be `r'(?P<prefix>A)?(?P<key>\S+?)(?(prefix)B?|B)$'`. This way `group('key')` would be non-greedy and a B at the optional if there is an A at the beginning. So, 'AanythingB' would correctly capture 'anything' in `key` group.

Answer (score 4):

```
(^A.*B$)|(^A.*$)|(^.*B$)
```

Comment: yes this matches but don't know which group in the replace part?

Comment: You can leave away the grouping of the alternatives, thanks to the precedence of the "|" operator, but would want to capture the relevant substring. This leaves you with ``^A(\S*)B$|^A(\S*)$|(\S*)B$``. The ugly thing here is that now you get the desired substring in one of three match groups, and you don't know which in advance. So you might want to use the 'max(match.groups())' approach of mykhal.

Answer (score 2):

`^A|B$` or `^A|.*B$` (depending whether the match function is matching from the beginning)

#### UPDATE

it's difficult to write single regexp for this..

a possibility is:

```
match = re.match(r'^(?:A(\S+))|(?:(\S+)B)$', string)
if match:
    capture = max(match.groups())
# because match.groups() is either (capture, None) or (None, capture)
```

Comment: actually what I need is to get the (\S+) group patten, `^A|.*B$` match  "`A`" "`anythingB`", but I need "`anything`"

Answer (score 2):

Is this the desired behavior?

```
var rx = /^((?:A)?)(.*?)((?:B)?)$/;
"Aanything".match(rx)
> ["Aanything", "A", "anything", ""]
"anythingB".match(rx)
> ["anythingB", "", "anything", "B"]
"AanythingB".match(rx)
> ["AanythingB", "A", "anything", "B"]
"anything".match(rx)
> ["anything", "", "anything", ""]
"AanythingB".replace(rx, '$1nothing$3');
> "AnothingB"
"AanythingB".replace(rx, '$2');
> "anything"
```

Comment: This regex misses the "not neither" requirement of the OP.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
/(^A|B$)/
```

Comment: While this matches at the right strings, it fails to capture the relevant substring, which is the actual difficulty here.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind the extra weight in the case where both prefix "A" and suffix "B" exist, you can use a shorter regex:

```
reMatcher= re.compile(r"(?<=\AA).*|.*(?=B\Z)")
```

(using `\A` for `^` and `\Z` for `$`)

This one keeps the "A" prefix (instead of the "B" prefix of your solution) when both "A" and "B" are at their respective corners:

```
'A text here' matches ' text here'
'more text hereB' matches 'more text here'
'AYES!B' matched 'AYES!'
'neither' doesn't match
```

Otherwise, a non-regex solution (some would say a more “Pythonic” one) is:

```
def strip_prefix_suffix(text, prefix, suffix):
    left =  len(prefix) if text.startswith(prefix) else 0
    right= -len(suffix) if text.endswith(suffix) else None
    return text[left:right] if left or right else None
```

If there is no match, the function returns `None` to differentiate from a possible `''` (e.g. when called as `strip_prefix_suffix('AB', 'A', 'B')`).

PS I should also say that this regex:

```
(?<=\AA).*(?=B\Z)|(?<=\AA).*|.*(?=B\Z)
```

*should* work, but it doesn't; it works just like the one I suggested, and I can't understand why. Breaking down the regex into parts, we can see something weird:

```
>>> text= 'AYES!B'
>>> re.compile('(?<=\\AA).*(?=B\\Z)').search(text).group(0)
'YES!'
>>> re.compile('(?<=\\AA).*').search(text).group(0)
'YES!B'
>>> re.compile('.*(?=B\\Z)').search(text).group(0)
'AYES!'
>>> re.compile('(?<=\\AA).*(?=B\\Z)|(?<=\\AA).*').search(text).group(0)
'YES!'
>>> re.compile('(?<=\\AA).*(?=B\\Z)|.*(?=B\\Z)').search(text).group(0)
'AYES!'
>>> re.compile('(?<=\\AA).*|.*(?=B\\Z)').search(text).group(0)
'AYES!'
>>> re.compile('(?<=\\AA).*(?=B\\Z)|(?<=\\AA).*|.*(?=B\\Z)').search(text).group(0)
'AYES!'
```

For some strange reason, the `.*(?=B\\Z)` subexpression takes precedence, even though it's the last alternative.

Comment: I've opened an [issue](http://bugs.python.org/issue10139) in the Python bug tracker, since it's a possible bug in the re engine.